# Xcode Project Size problem- 72 text files

Tags: iphone, xcode, submission

I am new to iphone sdk and creating my first application so please be nice when answering my questions.

I have following questions

Q-1. I have created a simple iphone application (not a game app, no OPenGL). My program is running fine but total xcode project size is 9 mb. I found that my xcode project size is less than 2 mb without "class" and "build" folder.

Do we upload files of "build" and "class" folder when we submit our application?

I have checked that most of iphone applications are less than 2 mb in size so I think build folder is just for me to test the application.

Can someone give me the list of all files or folders (just extension) that we need to upload in order to submit an iphone application.

Q-2. there are around 72 text files (each is 2 KB in size) in my program. Program open a text file according the selected criteria.  I have all 72 text files in resource folder. I am not using SQLite as I think it is not too much data and text files are small in size.

Can apple reject my application just because there 72 text files? Is it a common approach to use multiple text files instead of SQLite?

Q-3. Do I need to add zip and unzip my text files instead of opening them directly?

Q-4. some of my text files has following five words
      "sex" "sexy" "kinky" "filthy" "dirty"

For example "You are so kinky" , "I love sex" etc.

Do I need to remove these words from my files? Will they be considered vulgar? Will my application be rejected because of these five words?

I have seen some iphone applications on apple's website which shows sex positions and use words like sex,sexy,kinky so I think it should not be a problem.

Do I need to add something like  "mature content. Must be 18 years old" just because I am using these five words. I think these are pretty common words that are frequently used by young people.

Answer (score 3):

Many of these questions can be answered more completely by Apple's help docs in the iOS developer center and iOS Provisioning Portal (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action and https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action - you need to be logged in to view these links)

However, here are some quick answers:

1) The build and classes folder hold files during development. The build folder holds the binaries that are created every time you click 'Build' in Xcode, if you build for different targets, there will be multiple copies of your binary in this folder. It also contains various debugging and symbol files used by Xcode.

The classes folder contains all of the implementation (.m) and header files (.h) that you have in your project. This folder corresponds to the 'Classes' group in the file organizer when you open your project in Xcode.

When you submit an application to Apple, all you submit is the compiled binary (found in the appropriate folder in your 'build' folder). It is normal for your project folder to be many times bigger than the final binary you submit. For more info on the submission process, refer to the second link I posted above.

2) If you're persisting a lot of data, I would recommend using the built in SQLite database. It's very easy to use (Google will help you with this), and quite fast. Apple probably won't reject your app for storing a lot of data in flat text files, but you have no reason to. SQLite databases are much cleaner and easier to maintain than 72 flat files.

3) No. But you should still use SQLite, especially if you're saving enough data to these text files that they need to be compressed. Reading and parsing large text files can be much slower and more cumbersome than reading the same data from a database (databases are made to handle data storage like this).

4) Again, Apple probably won't reject you for this (of course, nobody actually knows why they reject apps, so it's always a bit of a crap shoot). When you submit your app, you can choose the rating level for it (sort of like game ratings, or movie ratings) so when people download it they are aware of the level of maturity of the content. One of the ratings is 17+, which you can use if you need. I believe Apple has a document outlining it's rating system in one of the links I posted above (or it's somewhere, it does exist).

Comment: As @Kyle states, you're not going to upload all of those files. In fact, from an upload perspective you'll only be sending one file, the compiled app inside the .ipa file. Mind you, an ipa is really a zipped archive with the binary, some support files, and any non-building files you include (graphics, text files if they're not programming code, etc.), but the file *count* inside that archive is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you don't need to upload build folder to upload but classes will be uploaded. you have to follow a process for uploading.
2. No problem at all you can upload even 1000 files, 72 is very small amount. but be careful that if you project is very heavy then it app will be crashed.
3. No need to zip the files.
4. you may use all of these words you may even use pornographic contents but they should not be copy righted of any body else. You don't need to remove them, when you will be uploading your application there will be an option "Application include adult contents" you just have to check that option.